# Problema para dividir variáveis em PHP

Tags: php, array, operadores

Estou tendo problema com uma página em php. Sempre que eu coloco o seguinte código para fazer a divisão de duas variáveis armazenadas em arrays

```
$dj_cv_at[percentual][$i] = ($dj_cv_at[concluida_c_imp_total][$i] / $dj_cv_at[concluida_total][$i]) * 100;
```

Como resultado a página deixa de funcionar corretamente.

Isto só acontece quando eu coloco o operador de divisão. Com os demais operadores o código roda perfeitamente.

Comment: dá algum erro, aparece? é problema com divisão por zero? casas decimais erradas? poderia detalhar melhor o problema.

Comment: Valeu, amigo já consegui resolver. O problema estava relacionado a divisão de 0 por 0. Para resolver o problema fiz assim: 
    if ($dj_cv_at[concluida_c_imp_total][$i] == 0){
$dj_cv_at[percentual][$i] = 0;
} else {$dj_cv_at[percentual][$i] =($dj_cv_at[concluida_c_imp_total][$i] / $dj_cv_at[concluida_total][$i]) * 100;}

Answer (score 0):

Após análise descobri que o problema estava relacionado a divisão de 0. Então para resolver isso fiz o seguinte:

```
if ($dj_cv_at[concluida_c_imp_total][$i] == 0){ 
$dj_cv_at[percentual][$i] = 0; } 
else {$dj_cv_at[percentual][$i] =($dj_cv_at[concluida_c_imp_total][$i] 
/ $dj_cv_at[concluida_total][$i]) * 100;}
```